# Pandorific dayofyear Comparison with Leap Years

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, leap-year

I'm a Pandas newbie and trying to do year over year comparisons for some years that include leap years.  They 'dayofyear' function is great..except when there are leap years.
Here's my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Day_of_Year'] = df['Date'].dt.dayofyear
## Deal with 2008 leap year
df_2008_1st = df[(df['Date'] >= '01/01/2008')
            & (df['Date'] <= '02/28/2008')]
df_2008_2nd = df[(df['Date'] >= '03/01/2008')
            & (df['Date'] <= '12/31/2008')]
df_2008_2nd['Day_of_Year'] = df_2008_2nd['Day_of_Year'] -1
df_2008 = df_2008_1st.append(df_2008_2nd)
```

My question is two part and one may be subjective.
First is, there's got to be a better, shorter and faster way to write this code. 
 This is working but it is a ton of coding for something that I am sure is easier to do.

Secondly, I'm going to make a year over year, daily comparison chart of sales numbers with this.  I don't know what standard practice is - reading the code suggestions for leap years I could find a hard and fast guide on how to handle this in practice.  Anyone care to share how they handle leap day data in practice?

Thank you,
Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this simplifies your code slightly by not creating and merging new DataFrames.

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df[(df['Date'] != '02/29/2008')] # this removes Feb, 29
df['Day_of_Year'] = df['Date'].dt.dayofyear

mask = (df['Date'] >= '03/01/2008') & (df['Date'] <= '12/31/2008')
df.loc[mask, 'Day_of_Year'] = df.loc[mask, 'Day_of_Year'] - 1

df.iloc[56:63]
```

```
    Date        Day_of_Year
56  2008-02-26  57
57  2008-02-27  58
58  2008-02-28  59
60  2008-03-01  60
61  2008-03-02  61
62  2008-03-03  62
63  2008-03-04  63
```

Depending on whether your situation allows, I would use the date as the index, which makes slicing and other date-based analysis much easier. (**Note:** the index and date parsing can be done when reading the csv.)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', index_col='Date', 
                  parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
df1 = df1[(df1.index != '02/29/2008')] # this removes Feb, 29
df1['Day_of_Year'] = df1.index.dayofyear
df1.loc['03/01/2008':'12/31/2008', 'Day_of_Year'] = df1.loc['03/01/2008':'12/31/2008', 'Day_of_Year'] - 1
```

You can then spot check using a slice like this:

```
df1.loc['02/26/2008':'3/3/2008']
```

Which returns:

```
            Day_of_Year
Date    
2008-02-26  57
2008-02-27  58
2008-02-28  59
2008-03-01  60
2008-03-02  61
2008-03-03  62
```

As far as how to handle leap days, this is probably more of a business decision, so it probably can't be answered here. But this question may be helpful: [Accounting for leap year in comparing year to year sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610752/accounting-for-leap-year-in-comparing-year-to-year-sales)

Answer (score 2):

You could make up an arbitrary index for each day like this:

`df['Day_of_Year'] = df['Date'].dt.month*31 + df['Date'].dt.day`

In this way, entries with the same 'Day_of_Year' value will correspond to the same date, irrespective of leap years.